# Generalised eigenvectors for Jordan chains

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

Supposing we have a matrix $B$ whose characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^4$ and $(B-I)^2=0$ holds true. How do I calculate the generalised eigenvalues of degree 2? For example take:
$$ \begin{matrix}
    1 & 0 & 2 & -1 \\
    0 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
    2 & 2 & 0 & 1 
   \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: is it correct to say that any vector is an gen. eigenvector of degree 2 as long as it is not a simple eigenvector?

Answer (score 0):

You may calculate $Z_1=$ ker $(B-I)$ (you find 2 vectors $u_1$ and $u_2$). Then pick arbitrarily two independent vectors in ker$(B-I)^2$ (which means any two vectors in the complement of $Z_1$) and find linear combinations that maps to $u_1$ and $u_2$, respectively. (Their existence is guaranteed by dim $Z_1$=2 and $(B-I)^2=0$).